# Why did I get a "bad operand types for binary operator" error?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, methods

I was working on an exercise which incorporates one method with another. I know that the `getMinMax()` method has an empty array but that's irrelevant for the purpose of the exercise.

Code:

```
public class Square{
    int area;

    public Square[] getMinMax(Square[][] arr){
        Square[] list = new Square[2];
        return list;
    }

    public int getArea(){
        return area;
    }

    public boolean isDifferenceSignificant(Square[][] arr){
        boolean isit = false;
        Square [] result = getMinMax (arr);
        if((result[1] - result[0])< 0.5) //The line (16) in question
            isit = true;
        return isit;
    }
}
```

When I compile this I get the following error:

```
Square.java:16: error: bad operand types for binary operator '-'
        if((result[1] - result[0])< 0.5)
                      ^
  first type:  Square
  second type: Square
1 error
```

I'm just lost and want to know why this error occurred.

Edit: Rohit Jain said "You probably meant - `result[1].getArea() - result[0].getArea()`"

and Lochemage said "if((result[1].getArea() - result[0].getArea())< 0.5)"

Both of these will work and thank you for your time!

Comment: You probably meant - `result[1].getArea() - result[0].getArea()`

Comment: @Heuster. OP has written that's irrelevant, in the first line. So, probably he is not returning an empty array.

Comment: @Rohit oops, missed that line :) just saw it one second before your comment

Comment: @RohitJain OP actually declared the `getMinMax` definition is irrelevant, not the `getArea`

Comment: @Lochemage. Yeah, that's what I was talking about. As, that is what can throw NPE, as it currently stands.

Comment: @RohitJain I think I got confused, maybe a comment was deleted, I thought your second comment was refer'ing to the `getArea() - getArea()` comment above it but you might have been responding to another one that was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you actually want to test the `area` variable of each `Square` instead?

```
if((result[1].getArea() - result[0].getArea())< 0.5)
```

By doing `result[1] - result[0]` you are invoking the binary subtraction operator from the `Square` class, which may not be defined.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have operator overloading like C++, and you can't subtract one object from another. Use the actual value (`result[1].getArea()`).